# creating a data frame after group by clause

Tags: pandas, preserve

I'm trying to dedupe a data set and convert the dedupe dataset to another data frame . However the deduped dataset has the first column as group by variables

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Cust':list('AAABBB'),'Dt':list('XXYYZZ'),'PA1':list('HHHMMH'),
                    'PA2': list('MLMMMM'),'PA3':[1,2,3,3,3,1] })

df2 = df.groupby('[Cust','Dt'], as_index=False).sum()

for col in ['PA1','PA2','PA3']:
    df2[col] = df.groupby(['Cust','Dt'],as_index=False)[col].apply( lambda x: 
                                              '&'.join( x.astype(str).unique() ))
```

This gives me Error
raise TypeError('incompatible index of inserted column '

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

I want the output copied to another data frame (df3) to display as 
(preserve the column order of the original dates- df)
The reason is the deduduped dataelements needs to loaded to a database and the layout (column order)  of the original (and the db schema) and deduped dataset should be same.

```
Cust Dt     PA1    PA2  PA3
A    X    1&2&3    H    M&L
B    Y    3&1     M&H    M
```

Thanks
PMV

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `as_index=False`, then reindex:

```
df3 = df.groupby('Cust', as_index=False).sum()
for col in ['PA1','PA2','PA3']:
    df3[col] = df.groupby('Cust', as_index=False)[col].apply( lambda x:
                                                  '&'.join( x.astype(str).unique() ))

In [11]: df3
Out[11]:
  Cust    PA3  PA1  PA2
0    A  1&2&3    H  M&L
1    B    3&1  M&H    M
    
In [12]: df3.reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
Out[12]:
  Cust  PA1  PA2    PA3
0    A    H  M&L  1&2&3
1    B  M&H    M    3&1
```

---

If you have the DataFrame with Cust as the index, you could `reset_index` instead:

```
In [21]: df2.reset_index().reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
Out[21]:
  Cust  PA1  PA2    PA3
0    A    H  M&L  1&2&3
1    B  M&H    M    3&1
```

Comment: This solution is not working in pandas .12.. It complains about incompatible index .. Is there a work around in .12

Comment: @pmv At which stage? I strongly recommend you upgrade your pandas, but there may be a workaaround here.

Comment: @Andy--I copied the actual example above. I have multiple group by cols. The example above has 2 group by cols